# Sencha Touch add individual records to store

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, extjs, sencha-touch

I have been fighting this one for a while. Seems so trivial, yet can't get it to go.
I just want to create a store, then slowly populate it with records based on UI actions. (Push a button > add the data to the store, push the next button > add that data to the store etc...)

Whenever I try to add the new record (after the first one has been added), the previous record gets wiped out and my store only has 1 record at all times.

How to add new records to the store (at different times, continuously adding new separate records)?

```
preparePost: function(data){

    //data is an object that comes from a button config...

    var mod = Ext.define('App.model.PostAttendanceModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        config: {
            identifier: {
                type: 'uuid'
            },
            fields:[
                'items'
            ]
        }
    });

    var createStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: mod,
        storeId:'PostAttendanceStore'
    });

    var getStore = Ext.getStore('PostAttendanceStore');

    var store = typeof createStore != "undefined" ? getStore : createStore;

    var items = {
            attendancereasonid: data.attendancereasonid,
            level: data.level,
            personid: data.personid
    };

    store.add(items);

    console.info(store);

    //it is always the last record added, without "previous" records!
}
```

Comment: Do you really want just one field `items` containing objects? Although it could be made working, the store is most similar to database table where fields hold primitive types. The above looks like a candidate for `attendancereasonid`, `level` and `personid` fields.

Comment: I plan to later send the items array to the server like this: http://screencast.com/t/owNf90fAtg

Comment: That are individual fields and the json like that is automatically generated by json writer. Go ahead with individual fields.

Comment: I agree with that, but still - it is only saving the one the record that is most recently added.  I cant add more than one record to my store for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, it didn't like when I created the model and store on the fly. So, I created the appropriate model and store files, put them in the proper MVC structure - and now the

```
 store.add(items)
```

method works.

Comment: the problem is that you created a model and store which name / id are already used, this will cause always problems

Comment: So is there a way to get around the issue, when preparePost() is being called at different times?

Comment: sorry, my comment should be only an explanation for your base problem, the solution with different files as MVC structure is just right.